# Getting attachment from Github Issues using the kohsuke Github-API

Tags: java, github, github-api

I want to download attachments added to Github issue.
I'm using an API [kohsuke](https://github.com/kohsuke/github-api)

Usually an attachment is added to in Issue into the body of the comment.

My problem is the `GHIssueComment` has a body as a String. So i can not get the attachments.

I could see that the `GHRepository` has a method `getBlob(String blobSha)`

But I do not know that this is what i need, also i do not know the blobSha.